# javafx listview item order

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm having trouble with JavaFXs ListView items. The thing is that I can not find a way to reorder them at runtime. Just with dragging item with mouse. Also I want to change items order in underlaying ObservableList.

How could this be done?

Comment: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2012/05/06/javafx-drag-and-drop-cell-in-listview/

Comment: There is some sample code for reordering items in a ListView via drag and drop in the answer to [How to create a reorder-able TableView in JavaFx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412445/how-to-create-a-reorder-able-tableview-in-javafx).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of the ObservableList that forms the underlying model of the ListView at any time to change the order of your list view items...

... for example: to use a Comparator to re-order the contents of your list view you could use something like:

```
javafx.scene.control.ListView<TYPE> listView; // Your ListView, defined somewhere else.

java.util.Collections.sort(listView.getItems(), new java.util.Comparator<TYPE>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TYPE o1, TYPE o2) {
        // Implement your comparator here.
    }
});
```

... whereas "TYPE" matches the type of your ListView instance.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#itemsProperty for further details of the list view items definition.
You can add, remove and shuffle the items around as you like and the ListView will automatically adjust it's appearance...

Comment: yes, thanks. Problem with my case is that I need to reorder items by dragging them with mouse. Not by code logic!
I found this blog post http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2012/05/06/javafx-drag-and-drop-cell-in-listview/ and this solution is working for me, but I think this is really complicated for such a thing...