# How to create a reorder-able TableView in JavaFx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a JavaFx `TableView`. I'd like to allow the user to click and drag to reorder the table rows. I can't seem to find any way to do this, but it seems like a pretty common thing in GUIs.

Comment: In all my TableViews you just click the header to reorder by that column.  You may have to write a custom comparator for some things.  If you mean dragging the columns to new positions, that works as well.

Comment: @brian I updated it to be clearer. I meant drag to reorder the table ROWS

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is some code to re-order rows in a ListView by dragging the rows.

Drag the birds to re-order them.

[image: birds]

Implementation for a TableView would be somewhat similar.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class ListOrganizer extends Application {
    private static final String PREFIX =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jozef89/origami-birds/72/bird";

    private static final String SUFFIX =
            "-icon.png";

    private static final ObservableList<String> birds = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "-black",
            "-blue",
            "-red",
            "-red-2",
            "-yellow",
            "s-green",
            "s-green-2"
    );

    private static final ObservableList<Image> birdImages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        birds.forEach(bird -> birdImages.add(new Image(PREFIX + bird + SUFFIX)));

        ListView<String> birdList = new ListView<>(birds);
        birdList.setCellFactory(param -> new BirdCell());
        birdList.setPrefWidth(180);

        VBox layout = new VBox(birdList);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(ListOrganizer.class);
    }

    private class BirdCell extends ListCell<String> {
        private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        public BirdCell() {
            ListCell thisCell = this;

            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                ObservableList<String> items = getListView().getItems();

                Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(getItem());
                dragboard.setDragView(
                    birdImages.get(
                        items.indexOf(
                            getItem()
                        )
                    )
                );
                dragboard.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragOver(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                       event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    setOpacity(0.3);
                }
            });

            setOnDragExited(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    setOpacity(1);
                }
            });

            setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;

                if (db.hasString()) {
                    ObservableList<String> items = getListView().getItems();
                    int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(db.getString());
                    int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());

                    Image temp = birdImages.get(draggedIdx);
                    birdImages.set(draggedIdx, birdImages.get(thisIdx));
                    birdImages.set(thisIdx, temp);

                    items.set(draggedIdx, getItem());
                    items.set(thisIdx, db.getString());

                    List<String> itemscopy = new ArrayList<>(getListView().getItems());
                    getListView().getItems().setAll(itemscopy);

                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                imageView.setImage(
                    birdImages.get(
                        getListView().getItems().indexOf(item)
                    )
                );
                setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        }
    }

    // Iconset Homepage: http://jozef89.deviantart.com/art/Origami-Birds-400642253
    // License: CC Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivate 3.0
    // Commercial usage: Not allowed    

}
```

Related:

- [Draggable list using a custom data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76285625/1155209).

Comment: I was able to port this over to a TableView by using the row factory instead of the cell.

Comment: Just a tip, this is not a good example. It does fit in the proposed scenario, but it fails to attend the possibility to replicate your code in other scenarios which not use a graphic inside the ListView cell. For instance, I'm trying to reproduce your code using a node (a label, more specifically) in the place of the ImageView, no success.

Comment: @FARS if you have a new question, please ask it as a new question which includes a [mcve].  This example was never designed to be a generic solution for all potential use cases of ListView re-ordering, it is merely a demo of one potential approach for solving re-ordering and has been useful for many other users.  If you believe that you have a better solution or a good alternative for this or other related use-cases, please post it as an answer.

Comment: I tried to do so.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176194/reordering-listview-cells-by-dragging-them didn't had success. I would appreciate it if you could provide an example of reordering ListView by dragging ListView's cells.. just as you did here, but replacing ImageView and Image with a Node of any kind (which does not use images, logically)

Comment: @FARS I cannot.  I do not have the time to do that at this time.

Comment: @FARS An [example implementation which does not use images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76284010/listview-drag-and-drop-error-indexoutofboundsexception-index-1-out-of-bounds/76285625#76285625).