# ListView drag&drop reorder items - best practice

Tags: listview, javafx

I wan't to reorder items in a `ListView` after drag&drop. It's not as easy to implement as it looks. Are there any efficient best practices to **reorder the items**, a helper class or library... or maybe javafx has a helper method?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a reorder-able TableView in JavaFx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412445/how-to-create-a-reorder-able-tableview-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution I just wrote for the problem. I'm sure there is a much more faster/efficient solution, but this works for me. The parameters has the following meanings:

- `dropIndex`: Index where the items are dropped / moved to.
- `listView`: The current `ListView`

*Here is the code:*

```
// save current selection temporarily
int[] indices = new int[listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().size()];
int j = 0;
for (Integer i : listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
    indices[j] = i;
    ++j;
}

// add items
listView.getItems().addAll(dropIndex, listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

// clear selection
listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

// change indices to remove items
int amountSmallerDropIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    if (indices[i] >= dropIndex) {
        indices[i] = indices[i] + indices.length;
    } else {
        amountSmallerDropIndex++;
    }
}

// remove items
for (int i = indices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    listView.getItems().remove(indices[i]);
}

// select moved items
listView.getSelectionModel().selectRange(dropIndex - amountSmallerDropIndex, dropIndex - amountSmallerDropIndex + indices.length);
```