# How to place JavaFX Objects inside ObservableList?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am trying to create a step by step flow similar to the one in this image

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/alU_Y2Uc3fA/maxresdefault.jpg

Where it says "Query Database" then an arrow pointing to next step "Load Page" and so on. I need something like that. I need the ability to move (Draggable), delete, add objects/steps.

What I have done so far:
I am using Rectangles for each step. I tried using a GridPane but that was a pain, no pun intended. I am now using a ListView horizontally. It appears to be working but I can't get the Rectangles to appear.

I also need to be able to click the rectanlges within the listView and have a new stage appear.

here is what I have.

Is there something else I can use instead of ListView that can do what I need?

```
public class singleStep{

           ObservableList<InstructionStep> obListSteps = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            public void onClickButtonAddStepToListView(){
                obListSteps.add(new AddStep());
                StepListViewFromMainWindow.setItems(obListSteps);

            }

}



public class AddStep{

   public AddStep(){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setArcHeight(5.0);
        rect.setArcWidth(5.0);
        rect.setHeight(58);
        rect.setWidth(66);
        rect.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

  }



    public void addStepPane(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader isLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/view/AddStep.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane = isLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            IAddStep is = isLoader.getController();
            primaryStepStage = new Stage();
            is.setStage(primaryStepStage);
            primaryStepStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStepStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            primaryStepStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: There is a [sample for performing drag and drop of items in a ListView here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412445/how-to-create-a-reorder-able-tableview-in-javafx).  Whether that will help you accomplish what you need, I don't know.  In general your question as it is currently worded is too broad for stackoverflow.  To answer the question title: `observableList.add(item)`, but I'm pretty sure that is not what you want...

Comment: One of the issues i am having is when an instance of AddStep() is add to the ObList and then loaded in the ListView, the result is not a Rectangle. The result is instead a string "controller.AddStep()@3bcb379f" what is causing this?

Comment: You need a cell factory Andy, see [Customizing the Content of a List View: Example 12-4 Creating a Cell Factory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm), or the example I linked earlier.