# JavaFX listView on-drag list items of type int[] ( Java Messsge:-1 )

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listitem

So i have quite a hard task of making my listview items dragable so i can change theyr index , items in listview are **int[]** so i use `CustomWeaponRecoilRowListCell<T> extends ListCell<T>`  with  param since i dont want to encapsulate my int[] in some object and i cant get any int array class to put there/there is none.

I follow amazing answer from Jewelsea [How to create a reorder-able TableView in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412445/how-to-create-a-reorder-able-tableview-in-javafx)

My first attempt was :

```
public class CustomWeaponRecoilRowListCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {

    private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public CustomWeaponRecoilRowListCell() {

        setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            if (getItem() == null) {
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<T> items = (ObservableList<T>) getListView().getItems();

            Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

            content.putString(CsgoRr.objectToJsonString(getItem()));

            dragboard.setDragView(textToImage(CsgoRr.objectToJsonString(getItem())));

            dragboard.setContent(content);
            event.consume();
        });

        setOnDragOver(event -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != this
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        setOnDragEntered(event -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != this
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                setOpacity(0.3);
            }
        });

        setOnDragExited(event -> {
            if (event.getGestureSource() != this
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                setOpacity(1);
            }
        });

        setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            if (getItem() == null) {
                return;
            }

            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;

            if (db.hasString()) {
                ObservableList<T> items = getListView().getItems();

                int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(db.getString());
                int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());

                items.set(draggedIdx, getItem());
                items.set(thisIdx, jsonRowStringToT(db.getString()));

                List<T> itemscopy = new ArrayList<>(getListView().getItems());
                getListView().getItems().setAll(itemscopy);

                success = true;
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(success);

            event.consume();
        });

        setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);
    }

    private T jsonRowStringToT(String jsonRow) {//take care of possible exceptions

        String[] row = jsonRow.replace("]", "").replace("[", "").split(",");
        int[] parsedRow = new int[RecoilPattern.PATTERN_WIDTH];
        for (int i = 0; i < RecoilPattern.PATTERN_WIDTH; i++) {
            parsedRow[i] = Integer.valueOf(row[i]);
        }
        return (T) parsedRow;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        int[] recoil = (int[]) item;
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            sb.append("[Number of steps:").append(recoil[0]).append(", Pixels per step:").
                    append(recoil[1]).append(", Direction:").append(RecoilPattern.directionToString(recoil[2])).append("]");

            setText(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
            sb.trimToSize();
        }
    }

    private static Image textToImage(String text) {
        Label label = new Label(text);

        label.setMinSize(80, 20);
        label.setMaxSize(80, 20);
        label.setPrefSize(80, 20);
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-text-fill:black;");
        label.setWrapText(true);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(label));
        WritableImage img = new WritableImage(80, 20);
        scene.snapshot(img);
        return img;
    }

}
```

Which  shows that im dragging i even create image from text of the data that i want to drag,that works  bud all i get into my STACKTRACE is :

> Java Messsge:-1

Thats super useless to me when i try to debug this , **this error is from when i drag and drop list item into another location in listview, no data has changed.**

**Why do i get this into my console? And no sensible stacktrace that i can work with?**

Gif of the problem:

[image]

Comment: If anybody can point out where this error message `Java Messsge` **with** the typo in Messsge comes from and why it seems to catch the real exception and stack trace... that would help.  Couldn't find it in JavaFX sources, While I had it also when dragging things around in a TreeView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out  what the problem was , first of all `draggedIdx` was always **-1** for some reason there was no way for me to get correct index value from jewelsea's answer tryed multiple ways even with cached value , index tracking / value was null at point of dragDetected, so i decided to get dragged index with `getListView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();`

This seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Within CustomWeaponRecoilRowListCell() you need to put a try and catch block on all of the code to get an appropriate stack trace message.

If printing the stack trace and solving the problem does not work try this gist, it worked for me fine: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/7821196

Good luck and let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: I literally linked that code into my question , its same.If there is something that would fail , i should get a response in  form of a stacktrace either way, this also didnt answered my question why i get error that i get and not usuall stacktrace as you get for instance when you run into npe thats not taken care of.