# ListView Drag and Drop, error "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 4"

Tags: java, javafx

i'm implementing a Drag and drop system for a ListView. I've drawn inspiration from this code:

https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/7821196

This is what i did:

```
package com.example.ratatouille23.View.Supervisore;



public class CategoryOrder {

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;

    ObservableList<Categoria> categorie;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        popolaListview();
    }

    private void popolaListview() {


        Piatto piatto1 = new Piatto("A", "B",
                "C",
                "D");

        ArrayList<Piatto> lista1 = new ArrayList<Piatto>();

        lista1.add(piatto1);



        Categoria cat1 = new Categoria("Antipasti", lista1);

        Categoria cat2 = new Categoria("Primi piatti", lista1);

        ArrayList<Categoria> listaCat = new ArrayList<Categoria>();

        listaCat.add(cat1);
        listaCat.add(cat2);
        listaCat.add(cat2);
        listaCat.add(cat1);


        categorie = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaCat);

        ListView<Categoria> listaCategorie = new ListView<>(categorie);
        listaCategorie.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Categoria>, ListCell<Categoria>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Categoria> call(ListView<Categoria> listaCategorie) {
                return new CategoriaCell();
            }
        });

        vbox.getChildren().add(listaCategorie);

    }



    private class CategoriaCell extends ListCell<Categoria> {

        public CategoriaCell() {
            ListCell thisCell = this;

            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }


                Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

                content.putString(String.valueOf(getItem()));

                dragboard.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragOver(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    setOpacity(0.3);
                }
            });

            setOnDragExited(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    setOpacity(1);
                }
            });

            setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                if (getItem().equals(null)) {
                    return;
                }

                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;

                if (db.hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    Categoria droppedCategory = (Categoria) db.getContent(
                            CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT
                    );

        
                    ObservableList<Categoria> items = getListView().getItems();


                    int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(droppedCategory);

                    int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());

                    Categoria temp = categorie.get(draggedIdx);
                    categorie.set(draggedIdx, categorie.get(thisIdx));
                    categorie.set(thisIdx, temp);

                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            });
            setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Categoria item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.getNome());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

These are my Piatto and Categoria classes:

```
package com.example.ratatouille23.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Categoria {

    private String nomeCategoria;
    private List<Piatto> listaPiatti;

    public Categoria(String nome, List<Piatto> lista) {
        this.nomeCategoria = nome;
        listaPiatti = lista;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nomeCategoria;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nomeCategoria = nome;
    }

    public List<Piatto> getPiatti() {
        return listaPiatti;
    }

    public void setPiatti(List<Piatto> piatti) {
        this.listaPiatti = piatti;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nomeCategoria;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Categoria categoria)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(nomeCategoria, categoria.nomeCategoria) && Objects.equals(listaPiatti, categoria.listaPiatti);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(nomeCategoria, listaPiatti);
    }
}




package com.example.ratatouille23.Model;

public class Piatto {
    private String nomePiatto;
    private String costoPiatto;
    private String allergeni;
    private String descrizione;

    public Piatto(String nomePiatto, String costoPiatto, String allergeni, String descrizione) {
        this.nomePiatto = nomePiatto;
        this.costoPiatto = costoPiatto;
        this.allergeni = allergeni;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getNomePiatto() {
        return nomePiatto;
    }

    public void setNomePiatto(String nomePiatto) {
        this.nomePiatto = nomePiatto;
    }

    public String getCostoPiatto() {
        return costoPiatto;
    }

    public void setCostoPiatto(String costoPiatto) {
        this.costoPiatto = costoPiatto;
    }

    public String getAllergeni() {
        return allergeni;
    }

    public void setAllergeni(String allergeni) {
        this.allergeni = allergeni;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nomePiatto;
    }
}
```

The code executes just fine, and my ListView is populated. When i drag and drop an element, however, this is the error it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
```

And the line that throws it is:

```
                event.consume();
```

I don't really know how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of using a custom data format when dragging a serializable record to reorder a list in a list view.

In the picture, the "Planet" category is in the process of being dragged over the "Star" category.  It would be a bit clearer if the drag cursor was shown, but the screenshot does not pick up the cursor.

[image]

You could modify it to use a custom class, but I find it easier to work with records for this case.

I won't go over what you are doing wrong in your current implementation, as [John Bollinger's answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76284109/1155209) have already covered most of that.

I won't explain this much, it is similar to the answer to the earlier related question (which, also, I didn't really explain :-), but modified for a custom data type rather than an image:

- [How to create a reorder-able TableView in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412445/how-to-create-a-reorder-able-tableview-in-javafx)

Hopefully, you can understand what is happening by reading the code, referring to the javadoc, and checking out the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag-drop.htm) and [cool example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/paper-doll.htm) on drag and drop in JavaFX.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class DraggableRecords extends Application {

    public record Category(
            String name,
            String description
    ) implements Serializable {}

    private static final ObservableList<Category> categories = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Category("Star", "A ball of hot plasma"),
            new Category("Planet", "A large, rounded astronomical body that is neither a star nor its remnant."),
            new Category("Galaxy", "A system of stars, bound together by gravity"),
            new Category("Universe", "All of space and time and their contents,")
    );

    private static final DataFormat CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT = new DataFormat(
            "application/jewelsea-category"
    );

    private static final String REORDER_CATEGORIES =
            "Drag the categories to order from largest to smallest";

    private static final String CATEGORIES_ARE_IN_ORDER =
            "The categories have been reordered correctly";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        do {
            Collections.shuffle(categories);
        } while (categoriesAreInOrder());

        ListView<Category> categoryListView = new ListView<>(categories);
        categoryListView.setCellFactory(param -> new CategoryCell());
        categoryListView.setPrefSize(
                430, 180
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(categoryListView);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setTitle(REORDER_CATEGORIES);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        categories.addListener((ListChangeListener<Category>) change -> {
            stage.setTitle(
                    categoriesAreInOrder()
                            ? CATEGORIES_ARE_IN_ORDER
                            : REORDER_CATEGORIES
            );
        });
    }

    private boolean categoriesAreInOrder() {
        List<String> displayedCategoryNames = categories.stream().map(
                Category::name
        ).toList();

        return displayedCategoryNames.equals(
                List.of("Universe", "Galaxy", "Star", "Planet")
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(DraggableRecords.class);
    }

    private static final class CategoryCell extends ListCell<Category> {
        public CategoryCell() {
            final ListCell<Category> thisCell = this;

            setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(getItem().toString());
                content.put(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT, getItem());

                dragboard.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragOver(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    setOpacity(0.3);
                }
            });

            setOnDragExited(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    setOpacity(1);
                }
            });

            setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;

                if (db.hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    Category droppedCategory = (Category) db.getContent(
                            CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT
                    );
                    ObservableList<Category> items = getListView().getItems();
                    int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(
                            droppedCategory
                    );
                    int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());

                    Category temp = categories.get(draggedIdx);
                    categories.set(draggedIdx, categories.get(thisIdx));
                    categories.set(thisIdx, temp);

                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Category item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            setText(
                    (empty || item == null)
                            ? null
                            : item.name + "\n" + item.description
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The solution provided isn't the only solution.  You could use a different serialization format (e.g. a JSON string) rather than the custom binary format used here.  That might be good if you need compatibility with other applications.  I won't demonstrate an alternative string serialization using JSON here though.

It is possible to place multiple entries in the `DragBoard` for the same item, with each entry providing a different representation of the same data.  I did that here, using a custom data format for the binary data and a string format, which just invokes `toString` on the item.  If you drag within the app, which understands the binary format, the app can use the binary format.  However, if you drag to something outside the app, which won't understand the custom format, it will fall back to the string format.  This can be seen by dragging items from the example into a text editor.

**FAQ**

> so i can make this work with Classes

For a class, generate `hashCode` and `equals` functions using your IDE and use equals instead of `==` to test equivalence, so that you avoid some of the issues mentioned by John Bollinger.

For a record you don't need to write the hashing and equals functions, or the accessor functions, as the records provide them.

Other than that, most of the implementation is the same regardless of whether you choose to use records or classes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


public class DraggableRecords extends Application {

    public static final class Category implements Serializable {
        private final String name;
        private final String description;

        public Category(String name, String description) {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Category category = (Category) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, category.name) && Objects.equals(description, category.description);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, description);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Category{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static final ObservableList<Category> categories = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Category("Star", "A ball of hot plasma."),
            new Category("Planet", "A large, rounded astronomical body that is neither a star nor its remnant."),
            new Category("Galaxy", "A system of stars, bound together by gravity."),
            new Category("Universe", "All of space and time and their contents.")
    );

    private static final DataFormat CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT = new DataFormat(
            "application/jewelsea-category"
    );

    private static final String REORDER_CATEGORIES =
            "Drag the categories to order from largest to smallest";

    private static final String CATEGORIES_ARE_IN_ORDER =
            "The categories have been reordered from correctly";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        do {
            Collections.shuffle(categories);
        } while (categoriesAreInOrder());

        ListView<Category> categoryListView = new ListView<>(categories);
        categoryListView.setCellFactory(param -> new CategoryCell());
        categoryListView.setPrefSize(
                430, 180
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(categoryListView);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setTitle(REORDER_CATEGORIES);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        categories.addListener((ListChangeListener<Category>) change -> {
            stage.setTitle(
                    categoriesAreInOrder()
                            ? CATEGORIES_ARE_IN_ORDER
                            : REORDER_CATEGORIES
            );
        });
    }

    private boolean categoriesAreInOrder() {
        List<String> displayedCategoryNames = categories.stream().map(
                Category::getName
        ).toList();

        return displayedCategoryNames.equals(
                List.of("Universe", "Galaxy", "Star", "Planet")
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(DraggableRecords.class);
    }

    private static final class CategoryCell extends ListCell<Category> {
        public CategoryCell() {
            final ListCell<Category> thisCell = this;

            setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(getItem().toString());
                content.put(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT, getItem());

                dragboard.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragOver(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                }

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    setOpacity(0.3);
                }
            });

            setOnDragExited(event -> {
                if (event.getGestureSource() != thisCell &&
                        event.getDragboard().hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    setOpacity(1);
                }
            });

            setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                if (getItem() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;

                if (db.hasContent(CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT)) {
                    Category droppedCategory = (Category) db.getContent(
                            CATEGORY_DATA_FORMAT
                    );
                    ObservableList<Category> items = getListView().getItems();
                    int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(
                            droppedCategory
                    );
                    int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());

                    Category temp = categories.get(draggedIdx);
                    categories.set(draggedIdx, categories.get(thisIdx));
                    categories.set(thisIdx, temp);

                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);

                event.consume();
            });

            setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Category item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            setText(
                    (empty || item == null)
                            ? null
                            : item.getName() + "\n" + item.getDescription()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the dedication. I'll study more about the documentation you posted, so i can make this work with Classes!

Comment: I just saw your edit, and that's what i implemented. It makes total sense because indexOf uses 'equals' of Categoria to compare the dragged element and compare it to the list, find the same object and take its id. Still... the dragged id is always -1, even after implementing the equals and hashcode (i use Intellij, and i auto generated the equals and hashcode), the problem is here. Do you have further advice to give me? I'm truly sorry if i'm looking stupid, but after hours of trying, maybe there's something i'm missing.

Comment: Also, i updated the code with the new 'setOnDragDropped' and the 'equals' and 'hashcode' in Categoria.

Comment: I would appreciate that so so much, take your time, you already did very much. And again, sorry if i'm sounding like such an hardhead!

Comment: Added class based example.

Comment: I thank you again one more time for your dedication. I finally was able to solve this! However i'll have to tell you... i found my problem. From your first example, i was actually able to change the code in the right way. You know why it wasn't working? The 'index=-1' problem was because Categoria has 2 variables, a String... and a List<Piatto>. And i've never implemented an 'equals' on Piatto. That's why indexOf always returned -1. I'm sorry you had to write an additional example for "nothing", but in the end everything is now working fine! Again, thank you!

Comment: It is not for nothing.  The purpose of the site is to help future readers.  So perhaps it will.

Answer (score 3):

Based primarily on the exception class and details message, if the code presented is responsible for the exception then it likely results from one of these `indexOf()` invocations returning -1 (to indicate that the searched-for item is not in the `items` list):

> ```
>                     int draggedIdx = items.indexOf(db.getString());
>                     int thisIdx = items.indexOf(getItem());
> ```

If either one is not found, then the subsequent

> ```
>                     Categoria temp = categorie.get(draggedIdx);
>                     categorie.set(draggedIdx, categorie.get(thisIdx));
>                     categorie.set(thisIdx, temp);
> ```

would throw exactly such an exception.

Indeed, since `items` is a `ObservableList<Categoria>`, it seems unlikely that `items.indexOf(db.getString())` could be expected ever to return other than -1, as `items` cannot contain any `String`s.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I took inspiration from the code i posted, but some things are not that clear to me. Since i don't use Strings, but a Categoria, what should i change to make it work? Because both Dragboard and Clipboard work with Strings, images... but with other Data types it's a little more complicated

Comment: @TrySoHard, you have a `ListView` of `Categoria`s.  There's nothing wrong with that, but it does have implications. In particular, when an item is dropped on your `ListView` you have to somehow obtain a `Categoria` from the `DragEvent`.  That could be by extracting one that is stored in the event already, or it could be by (re)constructing one from string or other contents obtainable from the event.  What you *cannot* do is store a String in the event when the drag is initiated, and then expect to find that string among the list items.

Comment: You may also find that you need to be cleverer about looking for existing items than using `indexOf()`.  As `Categoria` is presently implemented, it uses object identity as its measure of equality.  If you plan on an approach where you (re)construct `Categoria` objects at need instead of passing existing instances around, then different instances will compare unequal even if all their fields have the same values.  That might not produce the results you want.

Comment: Some of these comments would probably be better as part of an edited answer.  Also, on a phone, there is so much indenting of code in the code blocks that the code cannot be seen.